# Overlapping with ng-repeat and float: left

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to get two rows of `div`s via ng-repeat.
Every `div` has a `float: left` attribute and at the end I place a `div` with `clear: both`.

```
<div class="interval" ng-repeat="interval in intervals">
     <div class="text-center">
          <h2>{{interval}}</h2>
          <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-2x"></i>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="interval" ng-repeat="interval in intervals">
    <div class="testBar progress">
         <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
              <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

And css:

```
.interval {   
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px; 
    float: left;
}
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/uyrxd4ag/2/

But those two rows somehow overlap. But I do not know why since the `clear: both div` should prevent this.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: `.clearfix {}` is redundant, bootstrap already specifies `.clearfix`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interval divs have fixed height of 50px, that way the headings in the first row overlap with the second row. If you remove the fixed height, the height will be calculated correctly.